# Automatically try to sign in on initial page load using React, ideas on how to do that?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, react-router-dom

trying to use Microsoft's SSO with React, and I want to

`on first load to activate the method to attempt to sign in. So that I don't need to ask the user to click a button, it should just be automatic.`

I'm new to react and lifecycle methods, but it doesn't make sense to use componentWillLoad or componentDidLoad because it would just be checking everytime. Basically the whole site should be only viewable if logged in, so I believe setting up my protected paths after this should be doable

Any ideas on how to attempt this?

Edit:

```
      useEffect = () => {
             !this.props.account ? this.props.onSignIn() : <AuthWrapper/> 
        }, [];
```

Comment: Do it in componentDidMount Method of the root component. Yes, it will be fired every time the root component is mounted(ie during a page reload, or any state or prop change).  But you can check if user is already logged in(maybe check the localstorage)  and then fire the sso request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useEffect hook in react and pass in an empty dependency so that the effect is only called once on initial page load. The same thing could be done with componentDidMount. You could put a function within the hook or lifecycle method to check if the user is logged in then show different pages based on if that value. Something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // check here if user is logged in
  loggedIn ? showPageA : showPageB
}, []);
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do it in TS? In my edit above its yelling at me on the comma, expecting a ";"